# Table Row, when add padding to one cell the whole row gets pushed down

Tags: html, css, html-table, padding

I have a table, with some rows and columns, here is the example of the second row

```
<tr>
    <td valign="top" style="width: 150px;">
        <h5>MyCity</h5>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" style="width: 360px;">
        <h5 class="store_title">Store Title</h5>
        <p>address</p>
    </td>
    <td class="storeDescriptionCell"><div>Description
    </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I added storeDescriptionCell in my css

```
td.storeDescriptionCell{
padding:20px;
}
```

I even tried using the div, but everytime I add margin or padding to cell or div, MyCity, Store Title goes down with the Description. I just want the description to lay lower.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following CSS to set all `<td>` cells to vertical align top and the store description to vertical align bottom:

```
table td {
    vertical-align: top;
}

table td.storeDescriptionCell {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how html tables work. If you want one cell to be lower than the rest in a row you might want to try using a rowspan.

Can you provide an image of what you want and what you get.

Looking at the content that you want in your table why not use a th for the headings of the columns.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>My City</th>
    <th>Store Name</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>$content</td>
    <td>$content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I know how tables work, the thing is that for many reasons I am collecting all the data for the second and third row in $left and $right variable, so when i get to the cell I just do a echo "<td>$left</td>" and echo "<td>$right</td>", I will have to rewrite a lot of things.